# Convert decimal to text & back again in Java

Tags: java, decimal

I have been trying to convert text to decimal but failed, I searched but dint get results for java, text can be converted to binary then to decimal, but I want direct conversion and back again, please help me.

Comment: How have you been trying that? Can you show us some attempt along with an example input and the desired output?

Comment: Indeed, it's not clear to me what you mean by "convert text to decimal" to start with. Examples (along with what you've tried so far) would make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now that there are other answers (even though no effort was shown in the question), it feels like having to provide some alternative: A [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

See the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide a decimal as text
    String decimalText = "512.56";
    // use it directly in the constructor of a BigDecimal
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(decimalText);
    // and receive the double value of that BigDecimal
    double decimal = bigDecimal.doubleValue();
    // then output some representations of the objects resp. primitives
    System.out.println(
            String.format("Text: %s, BigDecimal.toPlainString(): %s, double: %f",
                        decimalText, bigDecimal.toPlainString(), decimal)
    );
}
```

which outputs

```
Text: 512.56, BigDecimal.toPlainString(): 512.56, double: 512,560000
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a decimal number in String format and want to convert it to decimal format and back. Did you Try the following:

```
String decimalAsString = "100.99";
double decimalAsDouble = Double.parseDouble(decimalAsString);
System.out.println("Decimal as Double: " + decimalAsDouble);

String decimalToStringAgain = Double.toString(decimalAsDouble);
System.out.println("Decimal as String: " + decimalToStringAgain);
```

Comment: No, I am trying to convert directlt text to decimal, not numbers

Comment: @KUMARASWAMYB.G decimals are numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean changing the datatype of a string to double, eg. if you have a string "6.23" and want to convert the datatype of double "6.23". you could use the parseDouble() method.

```
public class StringToDecimal {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringNum = "6.23";
    double decimalNum;

    decimalNum = Double.parseDouble(stringNum);

    System.out.println(decimalNum);
}
}
```